# Emacs compilation error on windows 10

Tags: emacs, makefile

When I compile code using emacs to the arduino I get this error:

```
make -k upload
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Fri Nov 25 20:23:04
```

I am running on windows 10. Do you have any ideas about what could be causing the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok now I am using Cygwin terminal to open it but I get a Spawning child process: invalid argument error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have the program "make" installed on your computer, or its installation directory is not on the `%PATH%`.

Check out http://www.mingw.org/ to get a GNU-like environment for Windows.